# What does this function input means in C language: MODELDIR "/en-us/en-us"

Tags: c, function, input, arguments, pocketsphinx

I read the following code from [the PocketSphinx tutorial](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx/)

```
config = cmd_ln_init(NULL, ps_args(), TRUE,
             "-hmm", MODELDIR "/en-us/en-us",
                 "-lm", MODELDIR "/en-us/en-us.lm.bin",
                 "-dict", MODELDIR "/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict",
                 NULL);
```

It's first time I see a variable--`MODELDIR`--beside a string--`"/en-us/en-us"`. How is this possible? I've never seen anything like this in C/C++ tutorial books!

If I want to search for more information about this, what keywords should I use for search?

Comment: MODELDIR will be a string-valued macro that will be concatenated to create a longer file or directory name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MODELDIR` is a **macro** expanding to a string. C joins adjacent strings into single ones*, so if `MODELDIR` would be `#define`d to `"/foo/bar"`, this would result in the following function call:

```
config = cmd_ln_init(NULL, ps_args(), TRUE,
             "-hmm", "/foo/bar/en-us/en-us",
                 "-lm", "/foo/bar/en-us/en-us.lm.bin",
                 "-dict", "/foo/bar/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict",
                 NULL);
```

---

*) So, writing

```
"Hello, " "World!"
```

is exactly the same as

```
"Hello, World!"
```

Comment: @user145959's example appears to be from a tutorial on Pocketsphinx: https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx/ . I got this to build just fine with gcc, but on a new installation of CLion, where I tried to add a few parameters to the CMakeLists file, I get: ```
[path]/hello_ps.c:16:5: warning: character constant too long for its type
     MODELDIR("en-us");
     ^
```